# Transferring data from one workbook to other based on a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one excel workbook to another workbook based on a condition. Both the workbooks have common column of EmpId (Column 1) and I want to transfer the salary (Column 2) from sheet1 of workbook1 to sheet1 of workbook2 of only those employees whose EmpId is present in 2nd workbook.

The code that I have written is :

```
Dim varSheetA As Worksheet
Dim varSheetB As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim myData As Workbook
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Path of destination sheet")
Set varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set varSheetB = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myData = wbkA
For i = 1 To 10
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To 10
        If varSheetA.Cells(j, 1).Value = varSheetB.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            varSheetB.Cells(j, 2).Value = varSheetB.Cells(i, 2).Value 
        End If
    Next j
Next i
myData.Save
```

I cant understand the problem in this code.

Comment: You should move `Dim j as Integer` above and outside of the `for i..` loop too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
varSheetB.Cells(j, 2).Value = varSheetB.Cells(i, 2).Value
```

It would make more sense if it was

```
varSheetB.Cells(j, 2).Value = varSheetA.Cells(i, 2).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

when you open a workbook this workbook becomes the activeworkbook. so when you set varsheetA=worksheets("sheet1") you refer to sheet1 of wbkA.

there seems also to be an incorrect reference to varsheetB when you copy the salary varsheetB.cells(j,2)=varsheetB.cells(i,2) shouldn't it be varsheetB.cells(j,2)=varsheetA.cells(i,2)

try this instead

```
Dim varSheetA As Worksheet
Dim varSheetB As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim myData As Workbook
Set varSheetA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wbka = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="d:\downloads\testsalary 2.xlsx")
Set varSheetB = wbka.Worksheets("Sheet1")
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
        If varSheetB.Cells(i, 1).Value = varSheetA.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            varSheetB.Cells(i, 2).Value = varSheetA.Cells(j, 2).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
wbka.Save
```

Comment: Still not having data in the corresponding columns. 
Thanks.